# Redux automatically return initalState after some action call

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, feathersjs

I am using react-redux and the reducer automatically return the inital state on call of an action, for example(given code) when i call the fetchPost action or the createPost action my Auth reducer automatically return the inital state.
why is it happening so i am using redux-thunk and backend with feathersJS.

```
export const login = (payload) => dispatch => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('feathers-jwt').then(r => {
        dispatch({ type: 'CHECK_AUTHORIZATION', payload: r })
    }).catch(() => {
        client.authenticate({
            strategy: 'local',
            email: payload.email,
            password: payload.password
        }).then(r => {;
            dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_REQUEST', payload: r })
        }).catch(e => {
            dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_ERROR', payload: e.message })
        })
    })
}

export const checkAuthorization = () => dispatch => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('feathers-jwt').then(r => {
        dispatch({ type: 'CHECK_AUTHORIZATION', payload: r });
     return client.passport.verifyJWT(r);
        }).then(payload => {
            dispatch({ type: 'JWT_PAYLOAD', payload: payload })
            return client.service('users').get(payload.userId);
        }).then(user => {
            client.set('user', user);
            client.get('user').then(user => {
                dispatch({ type: 'PROFILE', payload: user })
            })
        })
    .catch(() => {
        dispatch({ type: 'AUTHORIZATION_FAILED' })
    })
}

export const logout = (payload) => dispatch => {
    client.logout().then(r => dispatch({ type: 'LOG_OUT', payload: r }))
}
```

```
import actions from './actions';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

const initalState = {
  users: [],
  isAuthenticated: false,
  accessToken: null,
  profile: null,
  isVendor: false,
  isConsumer: false,
  errorMessage: null,
  jwtPayload: null
};

export default (state = initalState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'CHECK_AUTHORIZATION':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                accessToken: action.payload,
                isAuthenticated: true
            })
        case 'AUTHORIZATION_FAILED':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                isAuthenticated: initalState.isAuthenticated
            })
        case 'LOGIN_REQUEST':
            return (
                Object.assign({}, state, {
            accessToken: action.payload.accessToken,
            isAuthenticated: true,
        }));
        case 'JWT_PAYLOAD':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                jwtPayload: action.payload
            })
        case 'PROFILE':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                profile: action.payload
            })
        case 'LOGIN_ERROR':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                errorMessage: action.payload.message
            })
        case 'LOG_OUT': 
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                isAuthenticated: initalState.isAuthenticated,
                accessToken: null
            })
        default:
            return initalState;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting your default to

default:
      return state;

instead of 
default:
            return initalState;

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, we may put call an action upon form submit. Then page gets reload and entire redux gets initialized from beginning.

For an example,

```
<form>
  <button type="submit" onClick={()=>dispatch(someAction)}>Foo</button>
</form>
```

Above code will call that action and redux will once again initialize.